# How can I feed outputed augmented manifest file as input to blazingtext in a pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I'm creating a pipeline with multiple steps

One to preprocess a dataset and the other one takes the preprocessed one as an input to train a BlazingText model for classification

My first `ProcessingStep` outputs augmented manifest files

```
step_process = ProcessingStep(
name="Nab3Process",
processor=sklearn_processor,
inputs=[
  ProcessingInput(source=raw_input_data, destination=raw_dir),
  ProcessingInput(source=categories_input_data, destination=categories_dir)
],
outputs=[
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source=train_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source=validation_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source=test_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="mlb_train", source=mlb_data_train_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="mlb_validation", source=mlb_data_validation_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="mlb_test", source=mlb_data_test_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="le_vectorizer", source=le_vectorizer_dir),
    ProcessingOutput(output_name="mlb_vectorizer", source=mlb_vectorizer_dir)
],
code=preprocessing_dir)
```

But I'm having a hard time when I try to feed my `train` output as a `TrainingInput` to the model step to use it to train.

```
step_train = TrainingStep(
name="Nab3Train",
estimator=bt_train,
inputs={
    "train": TrainingInput(
        step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
            "train"
        ].S3Output.S3Uri,
        distribution="FullyReplicated",
        content_type="application/x-recordio",
        s3_data_type='AugmentedManifestFile',
        attribute_names=['source', 'label'],
        input_mode='Pipe',
        record_wrapping='RecordIO'
    ),
    "validation": TrainingInput(
        step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
            "validation"
        ].S3Output.S3Uri,
        distribution="FullyReplicated",
        content_type='application/x-recordio',
        s3_data_type='AugmentedManifestFile',
        attribute_names=['source', 'label'],
        input_mode='Pipe',
        record_wrapping='RecordIO'
    )
})
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
'FailureReason': 'ClientError: Could not download manifest file with S3 URL "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx/Nab3Process-xxxxxxxxxx/output/train". Please ensure that the bucket exists in the selected region (us-east-1), that the manifest file exists at that S3 URL, and that the role "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsUseRole" has "s3:GetObject" permissions on the manifest file. Error message from S3: The specified key does not exist.'
```

What Should I do?

[EDIT]

I made sure the role has the permissions, and the file exists in the required path in the required bucket, I even used the training files generated by a failed pipeline run as a static input to the model training process in a new pipeline run and it did well, the problem here is that the training step needs a file path, but the preprocessing step is outputting a directory path.

the traininbg step works with a path like this one

"s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx/Nab3Process-xxxxxxxxxx/output/train/train.json"

but not like this one

"s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx/Nab3Process-xxxxxxxxxx/output/train"

Comment: Have you followed up with the error message suggestions? Did you check the role? Does the bucket exist?

Comment: @KiritThadaka Yes, I made sure the role has the permissions, and the file exists in the required path in the required bucket, I even used the training files generated by a failed pipeline run as a static input to the model training process in a new pipeline run and it did well, the problem here is that the training step needs a file path, but the preprocessing step is outputting a directory path.

Comment: @KiritThadaka the model works with a path like this one "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx/Nab3Process-xxxxxxxxxx/output/train/train.json" but not like this one "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx/Nab3Process-xxxxxxxxxx/output/train"

Comment: Does `train_dir` point to a directory? Can you try setting it to point to the file written in the processing step instead?

f you choose AugmentedManifestFile, S3Uri identifies an object that is an augmented manifest file in JSON lines format. This file contains the data you want to use for model training. AugmentedManifestFile can only be used if the Channel's input mode is Pipe.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_S3DataSource.html#sagemaker-Type-S3DataSource-S3DataType